# How to play video file in jmeter

Tags: wordpress, video, jmeter, jwplayer

I have wordpress site with video player(JW player). I want to load test using jmeter. But i dont know how to do that?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

JMeter doesn't act like a browser hence it won't "play" the video via JWPlayer. If you need to check whether your wordpress deployment will be able to serve video content and the video content itself is being hosted by you it is possible to simulate hundreds and thousands of users which are downloading videos.

If you look into wordpress page source you will see something like

```
<span class="jwvideo" id="hero-video_media" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">
    <video x-webkit-airplay="allow" webkit-playsinline="" src="https://content.jwplatform.com/videos/XjiIpRcb-1080.mp4"></video>
</span>
```

You're interested in `https://content.jwplatform.com/videos/XjiIpRcb-1080.mp4` bit as this is the URL of the video file.

You can easily get the URL with the [XPath Extractor](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) using the following query:

```
//video/@src
```

And use simple [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to simulate video download.